# Scroll backwards and forwards through matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code produces a number of plots from data using matplotib and I would like to be able to scroll forwards and backwards through them in a live demonstration (maybe by pressing the forwards and backwards keys or using the mouse). Currently I have to save each one as an image separately and then use a separate image viewer to scroll through them. Is there any way of doing this entirely from within python?

Comment: Is the time required to generate the plots live too long for you to do just that? I.e. `press a button -> generate a plot -> show it` and so on.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I can generate them live but how do I scroll forwards and backwards through the plots I have created?

Comment: callbacks. See http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html .  As it stands this question is too broad.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An easy way to achieve that is storing in a list a tuple of the x and y arrays and then use a handler event that picks the next (x,y) pair to be plotted:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define your x and y arrays to be plotted
t = np.linspace(start=0, stop=2*np.pi, num=100)
y1 = np.cos(t)
y2 = np.sin(t)
y3 = np.tan(t)
plots = [(t,y1), (t,y2), (t,y3)]

# now the real code :) 
curr_pos = 0

def key_event(e):
    global curr_pos

    if e.key == "right":
        curr_pos = curr_pos + 1
    elif e.key == "left":
        curr_pos = curr_pos - 1
    else:
        return
    curr_pos = curr_pos % len(plots)

    ax.cla()
    ax.plot(plots[curr_pos][0], plots[curr_pos][1])
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', key_event)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(t,y1)
plt.show()
```

In this code I choose the `right` and `left` arrows to iterate, but you can change them.

Comment: Thanks much jabaldonedo--- your example is now in my project and so I can confirm for others that it works. In my case `key_event` is a closure within a closure inside a decorator. I do not fathom the cause--- so help me it's not erroneous punctuation on the end of the previous line--- but I kept getting "global name `curr_pos` not defined", notwithstanding the fact it is clearly defined by `curr_pos = 0`. I opted for a solution in the form `if not hasattr(key_event, "curr_pos"): key_event.curr_pos = 0` in place of `global curr_pos`. I would use `key_event.__dict__={}` to reset if needed.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me! I tried to comment out fig.canvas.draw() and it still works. Maybe it is not needed?

Comment: I don't understand how the namespace works in this example. I understand why `curr_pos` needs to be a global variable, but why then does `key_event` have access to the `plots` list and the `ax` axes instance?